# Qt Creator Resizing Widgets in Design Tab

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am having some difficulty resizing widgets inside a layout within the Qt Creator Design tab.

I want to have a vertical layout with a Grid Layout on the top part of the vertical layout and some buttons on the bottom of the vertical layout. When I set this up, the Grid Layout section and the Buttons section each take up exactly half of the screen as shown below.

Current Layout Screenshot

[image]

The design creator does not allow me to adjust the size of either section for some reason. I want to have the buttons only take up a small portion of the screen vertically (say 10%) and the Grid Layout take up the remainder of the screen (90%). How can I do that using the Qt Creator Design tab?

Comment: I don't see vertical layout in your screen. I only see horizontal layout for the buttons which is ok, and an _empty_ gridlayout. Your use case is not complete and the behavior will vary based on what you fill the gridlayout with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just populate the top layout with a place holder widget that you can use as a container, and set its vertical size policy to MinimumExpanding. You should get something like this:

[image: designer screenshot]

You can set size policies only on widgets, not on layouts. Therefore you can not achieve what you want without populating the top layout. Finally you can give the grid layout to the contents of the container widget.

Adjust the minimum size of your buttons if you want them to be higher.